# Issues in gradle parse android studio in Linux Ubuntu

Tags: android, parse-platform, gradle

The error code is: 
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.

> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 2
>   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gquy4.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this  add multiDex to build.gardle

```
defaultConfig {   
        // Enabling multidex support.
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
```